# Code about car park

Tags: python, arrays, queue

The laughs parking garage contains a single lane that hold up to ten cars. Cars arrive at the south end of the garage and leave from the north end. If a customer arrives to pick up a car
that is not northernmost, all the cars to the north of his car are moved out, his car is driven out,
and the others cars are restored in the same order that they were in originally.
Whenever a car leaves, all the cars to the south are moved forward. So that at all the
times all the empty spaces are in the south part of the garage.
Write python program to reads a group of input lines. Each line contains an “a” arrival or
a “d” departure and a license plate number. Cars are assumed to arrive and depart in the order
specified by the input. The program should print a message each time that a car arrives or
departs. When a car arrives, the massage should specify whether or not there is room for the car
in garage. If there is no room for a car, the car waits until there is room or until a departure line is
read for the car. When room becomes available, another massage should be printed. When a car
departs, the massage should include the number of times the car was moved within the garage
(including the departure itself but not the arrival), this number is 0 if the car departs from the
waiting line.

this is my code. i stuck in middle of the code. i made a queue to park the cars. i don't no how to reassemble the cars when a middle car is departed. and i want a way to print the number of moves before the car depart in park. so anyone can help me?`

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items =[]

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items ==[]

    def push(self,item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

class Queue:
    def __init__(self,maxSize):
        self.items =[]
        self._count = 0
        self._front = 0
        self._back = maxSize - 1


    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items ==[]

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.items.insert(0,item)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def index(self,item):
        return self.items.index(item)



q1park = Queue(maxSize=10)
q2wait= Queue()
q3assemble= Queue() 

x =raw_input("Car number: ")

def cararrival():
    if x[0]=="a":
        while q1park.size ==10:
            q1park.enqueue(x[1:len(x)])
            print(x + "car is arrived")

            if q1park.size ==10:
                print("No room available in the garage")

                x1=raw_input("do you want to wait: ")
                if x1=="yes":
                    q2wait.enqueue(x[1:len(x)])
                elif x1=="no":
                    print("see you next time")
               else:
                    print("Enter yes or no")


def cardepart():
    if x[0]=="d":
        if x[1:len(x)] in q1park:
            while not q1park.index(x[1:len(x)])==0:
                q3assemble.enqueue(q1park.dequeue())
                q3assemble.dequeue()

            while not q3assemble.isEmpty:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer for above question is here.

```
#creating a class for car
class Car:

    #initialization and creating properties
    def __init__(self, licenseNum):
        self.licenseNum = licenseNum
        self.moveCount = 0

    #increase the moveCount by 1
    def move(self):
        self.moveCount += 1

    #get information to a string
    def toString(self):
        return "Car {0}\tmoves:{1}".format(self.licenseNum, self.moveCount)


#creating queue class for cars
class CarQueue:

    #initialization
    def __init__(self):
        self.carList = []

    #add car to the queue
    def enqueue(self, car):
        self.carList.append(car)

    #remove car from the queue
    def dequeue(self):
        return self.carList.pop(0)

    #return the car by license plate number
    def getCar(self, licenseNum):
        for car in self.carList:
            if car.licenseNum == licenseNum:
                return car

    #check whether license plate number is in the car list or not
    def contains(self, licenseNum):
        return self.getCar(licenseNum)!=None

    #remove car from the list   
    def remove(self, car):
        if self.contains(car.licenseNum):
            self.carList.remove(car)

    #return the number of cars in the list  
    def size(self):
        return len(self.carList)

    #check whether list is empty of not
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.size()==0

    #return the index of the car in the list
    def positionOf(self, car):
        return self.carList.index(car)

    #move forward all the cars in southern side of the position.
    def moveCarsFrom(self, position):
        for c in self.carList[position:]:
            c.move()

    #get information to a string
    def toString(self):
        carNameList = []
        for car in self.carList:
            carNameList.append(car.licenseNum)
        return "[{0}]".format(" ".join(carNameList))


#creating class for the garage
class Garage:

    #initialization with the given number of rooms in the garage
    def __init__(self, maxSize):
        self.carQueue = CarQueue()
        self.maxSize = maxSize

    #add car to the list, when arrive
    def arrive(self, car):
        self.carQueue.enqueue(car)

    #remove car from the list and record movements of other cars to the southern side, when depart
    def depart(self, car):
        position = self.carQueue.positionOf(car)
        self.carQueue.remove(car)
        self.carQueue.moveCarsFrom(position)

    #check whether the garage is full or not
    def isFull(self):
        return self.carQueue.size()==self.maxSize



#create new garage which can hold up to 10 cars
garage = Garage(10)

#create new CarQueue to store waiting cars
waiting = CarQueue()

header = """
##############################################
               PARKING GARAGE
##############################################
Welcome!
"""

help = """
you have to input your command and press enter.
[a/d] [LICENSE PLATE NUMBER],   for car arrival or departure
    a,  arrival
    d,  departure

help,   show instructions
exit,   quit the programme
show,   show the queues in the garage and the waiting line
"""

#display the header
print("{0}Instructions:{1}\nPlease enter the command...".format(header, help))

#infinity loop to get user inputs again and again
while True:

    #get user command
    command = raw_input("\nlaughs> ")

    #excecuting general commands
    if command=="exit":
        print("Good bye!\n")
        break
    elif command=="help":
        print(help)
        continue
    elif command=="show":
        print("Garage        {0}: {1}".format(garage.carQueue.size(), garage.carQueue.toString()))
        print("Waiting line  {0}: {1}".format(waiting.size(), waiting.toString()))
        continue

    #get seperately the action character ('a' or 'd') and the license plate number from the command
    action = ""
    licenseNum = ""
    try:
        action,licenseNum = command.split()
    except:
        #show error message for invalid inputs
        print("Invalid input! Try again. Enter 'help' for instructions")
```